# antd adjusting input value in pagination dropdown

Tags: frontend, antd, styling

how can I rid off the '/ page' phrase in dropdown in Pagination in antd ?

[image]

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<Pagination/>` component, there is attribute called `locale`.

As per antd implementation, Object called `PaginationLocale` handles the Options data.

```
export interface PaginationLocale {
// Options.jsx
items_per_page?: string;
jump_to?: string;
jump_to_confirm?: string;
page?: string;

// Pagination.jsx
prev_page?: string;
next_page?: string;
prev_5?: string;
next_5?: string;
prev_3?: string;
next_3?: string;
}
```

To change the Lable of option values in the dropdown in Pagination we need to pass object for `locale` attribute with updated details.

```
// method to generate value for 'locale'
const getItemsPerPage = () => {
  return {
    items_per_page: "" // change this to empty string to remove '/ page'
  };
};

<Pagination
      showSizeChanger
      onShowSizeChange={onShowSizeChange}
      defaultCurrent={3}
      total={500}
      locale={getItemsPerPage()} // call 'getItemsPerPage' in render.
    />
```

With this you can remove '/ page' phrase from dropdown.

Here is the [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-pagination-dropdown-update-72934509-esg2yf) with full demo.

Comment: It works. Thank you. This attribute was no mentioned on ant.design official website. Where can I find extended documentation?

Comment: You're welcome. You can find those props used by going through the typescript files. `Ctrl + click` on the Component and it will open the relevant typescript file. And Feel free to Accept this answer and upvote if you feel it was useful to you. It will help to others coming here for solution.